# Integrate with a Step function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $s$ be a step function in $[a,b]$, i  need to do :

$$ \int_{a}^{b}s(x)\sin(x)$$

I can prove that $s(x)\sin(x)$ is integrable, but, at the time when i need to do the integral i need to divide this in the intervals $(t_{k-1}, t_{k})$ where the step function is constant, this is:

$$\int_{a}^{b}s(x)\sin(x) =\sum_{k=1}^{n} \int_{t_{k-1}}^{t_{k}}s(x)\sin(x) $$

I don't know if it's correct what i am doing here , because integration is defined in closed intervals.

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly correct. For the purpose of integration there is no need to distinguish between closed and open intervals because the "length" of the boundary points is 0.